# I need to open a particular accordion group on click of a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

For example: How to open a 2nd accordion group if i pass a particular value to a function. Below is my html code.

```
<uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="(menu,submenu) in leftNavData.leftNav" is-open="$first">
  <uib-accordion-heading>
    <span ng-click="location(submenu.url)">{{menu}}</span><i class="pull-right bold" ng-class="{'icon-downArrow': openIndex[$index], 'icon-fti_rightArrow': !openIndex[$index]}"></i>
  </uib-accordion-heading>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in submenu" ng-click="subMenuOpen($event)"><a ui-sref="{{value.url}}">{{value.text}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</uib-accordion-group>
```

Comment: Cant understand *particular value to a function* in your code. Which function & data are we talking about

Comment: @ShashankVivek: I need to open the 2nd accordion group if I pass a value "2" to a user defined function. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @ShashankVivek: Or if i pass the menu heading to the function i should be able to open that particular accordion group.

Comment: Which angular plugin are you using for accordion ? Share its url, and yes you can do but I need to understand the flow. If you want when the `div` is loaded then put it on `ng-init` . Add more details to help in understanding the scenario. Plunker can significantly help you here. Attach one asap

Comment: @ShashankVivek using the angular ui-boostrap accordion for the accordion functionality.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mb2brOUAk8H5O0LsTK3g?p=preview) should help you.Let me know if this isn't what you need. Note that I've used:

```
ng-click="selection($index)" is-open="check($index)"
```

to handle it.

Try passing accordion index using `$scope.userVal` in your controller.